# SSLCertVerificationError Error when running LangChain ArxivRetriever

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, python-3.10, langchain

I'm trying to run the ArxivRetriever in LangChain (specifically this example https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/indexes/retrievers/examples/arxiv.html) but I'm getting a SSLCertVerificationError after running

```
docs = retriever.get_relevant_documents(query='hello')
```

I have tried to install and uninstall certifi, but it's not working. Not sure if there is a way to set verify = False or do something with the certificate.

The specific error I'm getting is:

```
URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1007)>
```

I'm running python 3.10 and on a Mac.

Any help is really appreciated!